# Lifetime elision

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have struct

```
struct Cursor<'a> {
    chars: Chars<'a>,
}
```

what's the difference between

```
impl Cursor<'_> {
    fn new(input: &str) -> Cursor { ... }
}
```

and

```
impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    fn new(input: &'a str) -> Cursor<'a> { ... }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the first version is desugared as:

```rust
impl<'a> Cursor<'a> {
    fn new<'b>(input: &'b str) -> Cursor<'b> { ... }
}
```

That is, there are two distinct lifetimes.

However, I'm having hard time imagining any actual difference. The compiler will just infer to `'a` to be some lifetime, and you'll work only with `'b`, just like you work with `'a` in the second version.

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with lifetime elision. To quote [The Edition Guide](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/rust-1.36.0-docs-html/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/the-anonymous-lifetime.html#_-the-anonymous-lifetime):

> Rust 2018 allows you to explicitly mark where a lifetime is elided, for types where this elision might otherwise be unclear. To do this, you can use the special lifetime `'_` much like you can explicitly mark that a type is inferred with the syntax `let x: _ = ..;`.
>
> Let's say, for whatever reason, that we have a simple wrapper around `&'a str`:
>
> ```
> struct StrWrap<'a>(&'a str);
> ```
>
> In Rust 2015, you might have written:
>
> ```rust
> use std::fmt;
>
> fn make_wrapper(string: &str) -> StrWrap {
>     StrWrap(string)
> }
>
> impl<'a> fmt::Debug for StrWrap<'a> {
>     fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
>         fmt.write_str(self.0)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In Rust 2018, you can instead write:
>
> ```
> fn make_wrapper(string: &str) -> StrWrap<'_> {
>     StrWrap(string)
> }
>
> impl fmt::Debug for StrWrap<'_> {
>     fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
>         fmt.write_str(self.0)
>     }
> }
> ```